# How to create Sagemaker studio project using aws cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create sagemaker studio project using aws cdk following below steps:

create domain ([using this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-sagemaker-studio.git))
create user ([using this example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-sagemaker-studio.git))
create jupyter app
create project

Code for creating jupyter app:

```
def __init__(self, scope: Construct,
             construct_id: str, *,
             app_name: str,
             app_type: str,
             domain_id: str,
             user_profile_name: str,
             depends_on=None, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id)

    sagemaker_jupyter_app = sg.CfnApp(self, construct_id,
                                      app_name=app_name,
                                      app_type=app_type,
                                      domain_id=domain_id,
                                      user_profile_name=user_profile_name
                                      )
    sagemaker_jupyter_app.add_depends_on(depends_on_user_creation)
```

Code for creating project:

```
def __init__(self, scope: Construct,
             construct_id: str, *,
             project_name: str,
             project_description: str,
             product_id: str,
             depends_on=None,
             **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id)

    sagemaker_studio_project = sg.CfnProject(self, construct_id,
                                             project_name=project_name,
                                             service_catalog_provisioning_details={
                                                 "ProductId": "prod-7tjedn5dz4jrw"
                                             },
                                             project_description=project_description
                                             )
```

Domain, user, jupyter app all gets created successfully. The problem comes in with project.
Below is the error :

> Resource handler returned message: "Product prod-7tjedn5dz4jrw does
> not exist or access was denied (Service: SageMaker, Status Code: 400,
> Request ID: 768116aa-e77b-4691-a972-38b83093fdc4)" (RequestToken:
> 45ca2a0c-3f03-e3e0-f29d-d9443ff4dfc1, HandlerErrorCode:
> GeneralServiceException)

I am running this code from an ec2 instance that has SagemakerFullAccess
I also tried attaching SagemakerFullAccess execution role with project...but got the same error.
I have also attached below policy to my domain:

- AmazonSageMakerAdmin-ServiceCatalogProductsServiceRolePolicy

Comment: It exists. Its a cloudformation template for mlops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this was an issue related to IAM.
Running cdk program requires bootstrapping it using the command `cdk bootstrap`
After running this command cdk was creating a bunch of roles out of which one role will be related to cloudformation's execution role. Something like

> cdk-serialnumber-cfn-exec-role-Id-region

Now this role was used by cloudformation to run the stack.

Using sagemaker from console automatically adds the role associated with domain/user at

> ServiceCatalog -> Portfolios -> Imported -> Amazon SageMaker Solutions and ML Ops products -> Groups, roles, and users

Thats was the reason why product id was accessible from console.

After adding the role created by cdk bootsrap to the above path I was able to run my stack.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that the SageMaker Execution Role on the Studio Domain has access to SageMaker Projects. You can check by navigating to ServiceCatalog -> Portfolios -> Imported -> Amazon SageMaker Solutions and ML Ops products -> Groups, roles, and users.

Under this tab, you should see your domain's execution role. If you do not, please add it and then try creating the Project.

Comment: I can able to create project from console. For already existing user as well for newly created user. The users have sagemaker full access and domain is configured to allow user create project. From console all the project templates are accessible.

Comment: I tried the steps above. But no luck